# Anyway to relate two local mercurial repos to each other at some point?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

We have been using mercurial for over two years for our flex/as3 projects. Over the time, we came up with several projects and a common library which is used/referenced by the projects. In order to maintain the versioning properly, each time a new version is tagged on a project repo, the same tag is applied to library repo, as well.

This is done manually. I am not sure whether what we do which was described above is the correct way but I wonder if there is any (other) way to relate project repos to library repo, so that whenever i want to pull a specific version of a project, i will know exactly what version of library should be pulled.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried subrepo? By using subrepo, hg will maintain the whole project with the subrepo.

For example, if you have `HG_DIR/lib` as the library and it is a subrepo to the `HG_DIR`, then when committing in `HG_DIR`, hg will remember which rev of `HG_DIR/lib` you are using with, which means a commit in `HG_DIR` links with a commit in `HG_DIR/lib`.

`hg subrepo` supports multiple VCS subrepos, too.

Update:

As @alexis suggested, use recommendation from the [official documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Recommendations), lib should be treated as siblings of project:

```
HG_DIR/
    lib1/
    lib2/
    project/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know about subrepo feature. But I am not quite clear with how to share the lib with multiple projects using subrepo. Or, is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: @byrweb subrepo itself is a hg/git/svn repo, so you can keep its history. So in multiple projects, the libraries are subrepo for each project. In short, lib is a repo by itself, each project refers to lib by subrepo.

Comment: Read carefully the recommended ways to use subrepos. Don't make the library a subdirectory/suprepo of the main project; instead, have sister dirs for the library and for the main project. Enclose both in a container repo whose only job is to group these two together. (Otherwise you won't be able to commit to the real project without pulling in the library as well).

Comment: Sorry for taking longer to update my question, but this is a bit of research involved, and I need to read and test the documents you guys provided. I will post what I will come up with. Appreciate your time, thanks again.